# Join within a subquery

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

I need to use a join within a `count` subquery.

Here is my code, so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
select verticals.name,
        (select count(*) from `leads` where `id_vertical` = verticals.id) as `unique_leads`,
        (select count(*) from `lead_history` where `id_vertical` = verticals.id) as `all_leads`,
        (select count(a.*) 
            from `assignments` as a
            left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.id_lead)
            where l.id_vertical = verticals.id) as `assigned`
        from verticals
```

I'm getting a syntax error because I'm guessing my query is totally incorrect. What is the correct way of writing this?

Comment: Just use `count(*)` instead of `count(a.*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should fix the error:

```
select v.name,
       (select count(*) from `leads` where `id_vertical` = v.id) as `unique_leads`,
       (select count(*) from `lead_history` where `id_vertical` = v.id) as `all_leads`,
       (select count(*) 
        from `assignments` a left join
             `leads` l 
             on (l.id = a.id_lead)
        where l.id_vertical = v.id
       ) as `assigned`
from verticals v;
```

This also uses table aliases (for `verticals`) -- so the query is easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use join to increase query performance.

```
select t.id,t.name,
count(a.id) as unique_leads,
count(b.id) as all_leads,
count(c.id) as assigned
from verticals t
inner join leads a on a.id_vertical = t.id
inner join lead_history b on b.id_vertical = t.id
inner join assignments c on a.id = c.id_lead
group by t.id,t.name
```

Comment: This takes substantially longer to execute than my query.